# In Gerrit, what does this red dot mean?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, gerrit

After submitting a C# file in Gerrit, a red dot appears before the first line.

What does that red dot mean?

[image]

Comment: I don't know anything about Gerrit and don't know what diff tool this screenshot is from, but could it be a BOM was added?

Comment: What happens when you hover over it? (Googling for "gerrit red dot") seems to suggest it uses this action to provide more information

Comment: @CodeCaster you were correct! Feel free to make it an answer to get the points.

Comment: You are also correct in that hovering over it showed more information. You guys are excellent! Definitely worth the downvotes I had to eat to get this information.

Comment: Feel free to provide an answer yourself, assuming you have one ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this case, it was a byte-order marker.

It is also possible to simply hover over it to see what it is.